# Grab the pair of different items from two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am trying to create a file with only the pairs of items that differ in two lists. I would like it to be position limited: L1 [0] **!=** L2[0] --True (I want it!). L1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDYzL.png) **!=** L2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDYzL.png) --False (I don't want it).
However, my code is comparing each item from L1 with each item from L2 and returning undesired pairs.

```
l1 =  ["pear", "papaya", "guava"]
l2=   ["grape", "pear", "guava"]
```

The code
[image]

I just would like to have :

```
pear: grape
papaya: pear
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume the length.. then you can simply take the index and compare equal indexes.

```
l1 =  ["pear", "papaya", "guava"]
l2=   ["grape", "pear", "guava"]

for index in range(len(l1)):
    if (l1[index] != l2[index]):
        print(f'{l1[index]}: {l2[index]}')
```

Comment: Thank you!! I think I got the idea. Hope to be able to apply this more often.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the you lists have same length you can use the build-in function `zip` which return a generator of pairs.

```
l1 =  ["pear", "papaya", "guava"]
l2=   ["grape", "pear", "guava"]

print([f'{i}: {j}' for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i != j])
```

If the length are different a combinatorics approach is suggested.